# Is there a meta post/record regarding the disputes about the content of the classic regex-for-xhtml answer?

Tags: support, meta

Today I was reading this classic answer again:

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Below it I see a message that I guess I missed before:

> This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being
>   resolved. For more info [visit meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

The [link to meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) just goes to the meta home page. That surprised me; given the preceding text, I was expecting it to show me a meta post about the disputes, or something about their resolution. Leading me to the meta home page did not really seem helpful.

I'm just wondering, since meta was explicitly referenced in that lock message, *is there* some record of the disputes here on meta? Given the (pretty hilarious) [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1732454/revisions), I can get a sense of it. I'm just hoping for something more in-depth than that.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think that that messages necessarily indicates that there is an actual ongoing discussion on Meta. Rather that Meta would be the appropriate place for discussion about it. At least that's how I interpreted it when I noticed something similar for other questions.

Comment: No, there's no meta post. What "in depth" would you like to know? That answer has 19 moderator flags cast on it... 'Nuff said?  The lock was a "stop the insanity" move.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, just wanted to see if there was further discussion, since I thought based on the revision history that there might be some (sorry if that's a frivolous reason). Also, I suppose I was a little misled by the lock message, but Bart's comment explains that.

Comment: It appears the discussion is here, but I do agree with the OP. The answer by father monk @bobince has become the stuff of legend and should be treated with the respect and honour it deserves, oh holy one.

Comment: Since there is no dispute about its content, it appears that the lock itself is incorrect.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake: There **is** a constant dispute about the content. People think the Unicode text is an error and try to correct it, the rest of the community disputes that it is in error. [Most recent example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260356/what-is-wrong-in-flagging-an-answer-that-has-a-wrong-content-format).