# Can we do something about misleading message and link on locked questions?

Tags: feature-request, locked-questions

Locked questions get unhelpful messages like this:

[image]

My problem with this is that it implies that if I go to meta, I'll get more information about why that specific question is locked, perhaps finding a discussion of its merits.  However, the link just sends me to the main meta page, where I eventually realize there's nothing specific to the question.

Can we improve this situation?

Here are some suggestions (roughly in descending order of preference):

- make the link point to an actual discussion, on meta, of that question
- make the link point to the site-specific FAQ, specifically the portion that covers what is/is not acceptable content
- make the link point to some discussion/documentation of what happens when a question is locked, and how the process is resolved/closed
- change the wording of the message so it doesn't imply that there is any specifically relevant discussion on meta
- remove "For more info visit meta" bit altogether

Comment: For my opinion on this [visit meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: This has caused confusion before here on meta.  Check out [Is there a meta post/record regarding the disputes about the content of the classic regex-for-xhtml answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129577/is-there-a-meta-post-record-regarding-the-disputes-about-the-content-of-the-clas)  +1 from me.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113487/why-does-the-post-locked-explanation-suggest-visiting-meta-on-meta

Comment: @Toomai Did you somehow foresee the [croissant incident](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190106/dealing-with-find-out-whos-going-to-buy-the-croissants)?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler No the attention bounty was in response to it.

Answer (score 13):

I like:

> - make the link point to an actual discussion, on meta, of that question

Perhaps that can happen automatically. There is already a list of "linked posts" maintained automatically. This is "just" a cross-site linked posts feature, shown in a different place. For most sites this is likely to be between the per-site meta and main, not the broader problem.

If a meta question really is discussing a question on the main site then it ought to have a link of one form or another in it. This could happen for any question being discussed on the per site meta somewhere - users will learn about meta and be generally more informed about site/question issues.

For the case of SO and MSO which is not a site specific meta this might be a bit more complicated to manage, but last I saw SO was supposed to get its own proper meta soon.

Linking like this would be useful for small beta sites (we're defining our policies/topic right now) and large sites (this is being discussed further).

Comment: +1 / cross-site link - that's my cue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59569/display-other-se-site-links-in-the-linked-questions-sidebar

Answer (score 4):

Interesting idea. I'd like to see a combination of your suggestions implemented, where the word "locked" is a link, and links to the explanation of locking, and the "visit meta" is a link to a meta post specifically about that locked question.

Of course, this would require that a meta post be created for it. I think it would be a good idea to either automatically create one when a question is locked, or allow the locking moderator to link to an existing one. Since "disputes about its content are being resolved", there will inevitably be a meta discussion anyway (or there at least should be), so pointing people to it will be useful.