# Have locked question directly link to its respective meta discussion if existing

Tags: feature-request, locked-questions

If a question gets locked, there often is a meta discussion related to it, e.g. in the recent [croissant case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807531/find-out-whos-going-to-buy-the-croissants). While there is a [prominent highly upvoted comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807531/find-out-whos-going-to-buy-the-croissants#comment26023885_17807531) linking to [its meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190106/dealing-with-find-out-whos-going-to-buy-the-croissants), the "locked by..." message only links to meta in general:

[image: locked link lacking]

Therefore, *if* such a discussion exists when (or gets created after) a post gets locked, the "visit meta" link should directly link there instead.

Comment: Wait a sec... seems to be a similar request already, though the wording is different: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141669/can-we-do-something-about-misleading-message-and-link-on-locked-questions (just noticed it's from a year ago too)

Comment: @OldCheckmark Thanks, that's indeed basically the same. It even got a bounty just two days ago - before the croissant incident!